# F# Type inference on Math.Max

Tags: .net, f#

Why won't the compiler pick the correct version of an overloaded method if it has inferred the types of the input parameters.

In this example why can't it pick the correct Math.Max to use when the type has correctly inferred on the elements being compared:

```
let listMax = 
    List.map2 (fun l r -> Math.Max(l,r)) [2;4] [5;3]       //compile error 
let listMax2 = 
    List.map2 (fun (l:int) r -> Math.Max(l,r)) [2;4] [5;3] //no compile error
```

Of course you can just use the max function in this case, but there are plenty of other methods that don't have a native equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Gos correctly points out, using the pipeline operator helps in this case. The reason is that the type inference works from left to right - so, if you use the pipeline operator, it knows that one of the inputs is a list of integers and, based on that, it picks the right overload of `Math.Max`.

The compiler generally needs to know the type when it does overload resolution or when you want to invoke a member on a object (e.g. if you wanted to do `l.Foo()` inside the map function) - because in this case, it needs to know what exactly the type is.

F# also defines its own versions of basic math functions which work better with type inference. So you can replace `Math.Max` with the `max` functions (which you can also nicely pass directly to `map2`):

```
List.map2 max [2;4] [5;3]
```

This works better, because F# does not need to perform overload resolution (the function is not overloaded). It just keeps track of a special *generic constraint* that is satisfied and resolved later.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What I don't quite understand is that the type inference is working correctly in the top example, l & r are correctly identified as int. So why can't it pick the correct Max without the order change?

Comment: @FsharpPete The type inference works by refining some initial knowledge about the types. So, when it gets to `Math.Max` in the first case, it only knows that they are some values of (generic) types `'a` and `'b`. This is not enough to resolve `Math.Max`, so it records an error and then finishes processing the rest of the file - where it finds the list and refines `'a` and `'b` to `int`. In the version with `max` it works because it adds a constraint that `'a` and `'b` must support taking the maximum...

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why but I found that the pipeline operator often helps type inference:

```
let listMax = 
    [5;3] |> List.map2 (fun l r -> Math.Max(l,r)) [2;4]
```

Comment: This is because, as in Tomas' answer, type inference is left to right.